# Не могу отправить два запроса post в функции jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Я пытаюсь отправить два запроса post одним кликом в jquery.

```
$('.any_class').click( function {

   $.post(
   "/functions/function1.php", {
       data: $(this).data('id')
   }),

   $.post(
   "/functions/function2.php", {
       data: $(this).data('another_id')
   }),

});
```

На удивление первый отрабатывает, второй игнорируется. Код был написан для примера.

Comment: вы в скобках-кавычках заблудились. каша какая-то в примере

Comment: что значит `},` в коонце каждого `post` ? и где закрывающие круглые скобки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще странно почему код работал. Вероятней всего две или больше ошибки наложились друг на друга и компенсировали.

А рабочий пример должен выглядеть примерно вот так.

```js
$('.any_class').click( function {

   //первый post
   $.post(
   "/functions/function1.php", {
       data: $(this).data('id')
   });

   //второй
   $.post(
   "/functions/function2.php", {
       data: $(this).data('another_id')
   });

});
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, благодарю за ответ, у вас правильное решение

Answer (score -2):

Мне кажется, вы запутались в скобках. У вас есть открывающая скобка `$.post(` , но нет закрывающей, могу предположить, что причина именно в этом.
Попробуйте так -

```
$('.any_class').click( function {

   $.post(
   "/functions/function1.php", {
       data: $(this).data('id')
   }),
   $.post(
   "/functions/function2.php", {
       data: $(this).data('another_id')
   }),

});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо, изменил

Comment: по-моему, вы тоже запутались )